# Show that if G is a group with $G = p ^ n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Show that if G is a group with $$|G| = p ^ n,$$ where p is prime and $n ∈\mathbb N$, then Z (G) (i.e. the center of G) must have at least p elements.

It is not an assignment question I only saw a similar exercise in a book and I want to know how it would be solved.

I think it can be done with the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem because each orbit has size a power of p, and the orbit sizes sum to $$p^n$$ So,the number of elements
not in Z(G) is divisible by p, whence the number in Z(G) is also. But there is at
least one element in Z(G), namely the identity; so there are at least p such elements.Now, if g is an element of order p in Z(G), then  is a normal subgroup of G of order p. I do not know if it is so, thanks in advance.

I would like to know how it would be using the class equation...

Comment: I think your argument is correct, but I don't know why the sentence "Now, if $g$ is an element of order $p$ in $Z(G)$, then is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p$" is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most direct way to do this is by using the Class Equation which is derived easily from the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem by considering, the group, G acting on itself by conjugation.

The class equation says $$|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(G:C_G(g_i))$$.  Now since $|G| = p^n$, and each $(G:C_G(g_i))$ divides |G|, then $p$ divides $(G:C_G(g_i))$ and so p divides the sum on the left side of the class equation.  Therefore $p$ divides $|Z(G)|$.

Comment: You're right with the class equation I think it would be simpler, but how would it be?